# How to upload dynamically generated video thumbnails as a BLOB into MySQL database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ffmpeg, blob

Here is the code that has been used to create a thumbnail of a uploaded video. The thumbnail is automatically generated successfully, but now, I want to store that thumbnail as a BLOB in the Database.
I know how to upload an image as a BLOB using form posts, but there is no form posts involved in this.

Could someone guide me through this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
 </form>
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  /*
  -i input file name
  -an Disabled audio
  -ss Get image from x seconds in the video
  -s  size of the image
  */
  //Get one thumbnail from the video
  $ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
  //echo $ffmpeg;
  $videoFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  $imageFile = "1.jpg";
  $size = "120x90";
  $getFromSecond = 5;

  //echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES); die;
  //echo "video location: ",$videoFile,"<br>";
  echo $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -an -ss $getFromSecond -s $size $imageFile";

  echo "<br>";
  if(!shell_exec($cmd)){
   echo "Thumbnail Created!";
  }else{
   echo "Error creating Thumbnail";
  }

  /*// Get multiple thumbnails from one video
  $ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
  $videoFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  $size = "120x90";
  for($num =1; $num<=3; $num++){
   $interval = $num * 3;
   shell_exec("$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -an -ss $interval -s $size $num.jpg");
   echo "Thumbnail Created!- $num.jpg<br/>";
  }
  echo "<br/>$num thumbnails Created!";
  */
 } 
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create a table that has vidio name, and image as fields then change image field to long text and then just use mysql/mysqli to store it

Comment: @MasterT Either I didn't understand what you said, or You didn't understand what I meant. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
Example : Run in command prompt

ffmpeg -y -itsoffset -4 -i C:\xampp\htdocs\application\videos\kwc.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg   -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo C:\xampp\htdocs\application\thumbnails\test.jpg

NOTE:  
Here C:\xampp\htdocs\application\videos\kwc.mp4 is a video path and C:\xampp\htdocs\application\thumbnails\test.jpg is a thumbnail path where you should store.
```